# Show mouse position while clicking by jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, coordinates, mousemove, mousedown

I want to make a rotation tool in my site, in an image inside a canvas. As I first step I want to find the mouse co-ordinates every time, so as to force later the image to rotate according to this. 
I know that I can use mousemove which will give me the coordinates as long as I am moving the mouse. But what I want, is to keep the mouse pressed and moving it and then get the coordinates. So not just mousemove but mouse clicked and move.
Is there a way to do something like that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a combined event, but you could set a variable to check whether the mouse is held down then only deal with the coords if it's true? See: http://jsfiddle.net/Vrpd3/1/

The 'mouseout' event is to stop it recording after you drag out of the element, release the click then hover back over.

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know also if is possible to add this on() event on a canvas? Because I think is not working on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this page.

You can change it according to your need.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

its a draggable facility of Jquery.

```
$('#id').draggable({
drag: function(event, ui) {
    var toppos =ui.position.top
    var leftpos = ui.position.left
}
});
```

So for each drag you can know the position of the draggable object. and yes you will get relative position from the position where you have initially put your draggable div. and not the absolute within the page.

Comment: I want to do something similar to draggable, but I have no div I want the selector to be my mouse, so as to get the X,Y of it.

Comment: If so , I cannot exactly understand what you want to achieve , adding the code you've written so far would be helpful

Comment: Check the edited answer. you should be fine with dragging a div and getting position. i am not sure if that fulfils your requirement.

Comment: I do not have an id. I have not element let's say. I just have a mouse moving inside an element. So I do not want to drag the element, I just want to see the mouse coordinates when the mouse in down and moved.

Comment: Sorry, In that case this example is not useful. But it's worth to have a look at this. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Answer (score 0):

If what you aim to do is getting X,Y cords while moving the mouse as it's clicked,  check out this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itamarperetz/cuZLd/)
*Most of the code is taken directly from jQuery documentation , I've just made few changes.
**If you want to drag an object an getting the cordinated while dragging, I've got you wrong and the example above is not useful for your case**

Comment: yes but this one it shows X,Y on mouseover. I want to show them on when the mouse is pressed and moving.

Comment: if you also want the square to move , import the jQuery draggable ui and make it draggable by $(."square").draggable();